# Is it possible to use an aws role instead of keys for Minikube registry creds addon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, minikube

I have a minikube cluster that pulls images from ECR. As I have things set up, my credentials refresh every day, therefore each day I need to input these credentials, run them through the registry creds addon. Is there a way of using the registry creds addon with an assumed IAM role instead of credentials?

Comment: I think that roles are suppose to be used with aws resources, maybe I am wrong, but How aws will recognize your minikube?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam) to match useraccount with role in aws

Take a look at below links:

- https://www.bluematador.com/blog/iam-access-in-kubernetes-installing-kube2iam-in-production
- https://medium.com/@marcincuber/amazon-eks-iam-roles-and-kube2iam-4ae5906318be